# Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Decimal.?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I have following `ADO.NET` code in which i am facing the exception as :

```
Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Decimal.
```

This code was running perfectly until last night but i think there is happened something unusual.

```
try
{
    da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO ITEM_DETAILS VALUES(@ITEM_MODEL,@ITEM_NAME,@ITEM_DESCRIPTION,@VENDOR_NAME,@QUANTITY,@RATE,'',@INVOICE_NUM,@DATE,@Discount)", con);
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ITEM_MODEL", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtItemModel.Text;
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ITEM_NAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtItemName.Text;
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ITEM_DESCRIPTION", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtItemDescription.Text;
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@VENDOR_NAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtVendor.Text;
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@QUANTITY", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtQuantity.Text;
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@RATE", SqlDbType.Money).Value = txtRate.Text;
    // da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@AMOUNT", SqlDbType.Money).Value = txtAmount.Text;
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@INVOICE_NUM", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtInvoice.Text;
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DATE", SqlDbType.Date).Value = (dateTimePicker1.Value);
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Discount", SqlDbType.Money).Value = txtDiscount.Text;
    con.Open();
    da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("Something wrong enters", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
}
```

I tried but didnt find solution to this exception.Any help would be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your definition of the `INSERT` statement, between your `@RATE` and `@INVOICE_NUM`, you are introducing an empty string value. Maybe can be this the problem?

Using your `Parameters.Add` method call I will expect that in this place could be the `@AMOUNT` parameter, that is actually commented. Perhaps this is the reason that you sets the column value directly to `''`.

Try to replace `''` value with `0`, if this value is correct for you.